# could someone explain navigation drawer code

Tags: android

`enter code here`I have a problem with understanding the code that create navigation drawer and what is actionbardrawertoggle represent can someone explain the whole code in detail?

```
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

also this

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, there!  
Can you reformulate your question with a concise  question and code example?

Answer (score 0):

The first part is just find view by id, connection the drawer to the layout and adding the icon on the toolbar.

onBackPressed part will handle the event when your drawer is open and user presses the back button, the drawer will close. If the drawer is closed then it's going to call the super.

Comment: what about actionbardrawertoggle

Comment: ActionBarDrawerToggle is used to add listener to the drawer and to add the hamburger menu icon.